# Any opinions of Telinga EM-23

Tags: self-noise, nature-recording

Does anyone have any experience using the [Telinga EM-23](http://www.telinga.com/products/pro-series/microphones/stand-alone/em-23-pair/)

The DPA 4060 is so ubiquitous now, I was surprised to find that the EM-23 has 14 - 16dB(A) self noise, compared to the 4060s 23dB(A). Interested to hear any opinions on the actual sound and tone of the EM-23 as I would snap this up in an instant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EM-23s has a very nice low end and brilliant signal to noise.  The capsules are not as cheap as a few bucks each (like other cheaper Primso) but they cost like 50-60 USD / capsule, then you need fet:s, then you need housing etc. but of course if you got very nice soldering skills you may do better then me =) / Pete

Comment: I can solder, but wouldn't say I'm skilled! :) I guess I can just add these to the ever growing gear wish list!

Answer (score 1):

Well...haven't used them, but supposedly, they use Primo electret capsules, which can Be had for just a few Bucks each. The Sony pcm m10 uses primo capsules with a noise floor similar to that of Telinga. So if you can solder, look for primo em23. Also, search taperssection.com for telinga em23 pip for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wonder is the same noise floor achievable going the custom route though? There's surely extra electronics in the Telinga model that warrant the price?

Comment: You're right of course. The em23 uses an external fet and accompanying components. It is also not as cheap as the em172 I am using, which is about the same wrt noise, but has an internal fet. That One is about 10$. It is supposedly the capsule uses in the Sony pcm m10. Very, very quiet, IF tou set the gain right.